# Should we be more measured in how we regard Theoi?

Tags: discussion

Theoi is useful and incredibly convenient, but it it is *not* definitive, nor peer-reviewed:

- Listed passages on a given subject are often assumed to be the complete body of material, which may not be the case.
- Only a single translation of a given passage is offered
- As these translations are often old (i.e. in the public domain which is why they may be utilized) and can contain inaccuracies.

Theoi, like Wikipedia, is a great starting place, and serves an online function similar to Graves' [The Greek Myths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greek_Myths) with it's useful index, albeit in a much more limited capacity, containing only a fraction of the subjects covered in Graves, and no peer review.

In other words, Theoi is not an academic source, but it is commonly treated as one: https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/265/2892

Comment: @bleh Actually, you're an excellent researcher for the most part, and your endeavors demonstrate the value of a resource like Theoi.  But on certain subjects, broadening the search will lead to more complete information and deeper meanings.

Comment: @Gibet Agreed. I always prefer the source text over secondary sources. It's the only way to generate useful insights, imo. Andejons and Solsdottir are rockstars because they cite academic sources in addition to the originals, and offer context so that one can easily grasp how the info fits into the bigger picture.